# Burning money on Amazon EC2

Tags: amazon-ec2

Where on the [AWS Management Console](https://console.aws.amazon.com/) can I see how much money I'm burning per hour with my Amazon EC2 service?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Navigate to:

Amazon Web Services > Account > Account Activity

Expand the entry under Amazon Elastic Compute Cloud

That will show the full breakdown of the hours used and the cost to you. Simply divide to find your hourly cost.

---

If you want to be more granular, you can download your Usage Report:

Amazon Web Services > Account > Usage Reports

https://aws-portal.amazon.com/gp/aws/developer/account/usage-report.html

Set report granularity to Hours and click 'Download Report'. However, this report does not include the costs.